# Go Programming Language Interface Conceptual Understanding

Tags: go

I am writing a sample Http Client/Server code to learn more about Go. During the process of writing I needed to read the response Body. So I looked at the Go Pkg Documentation http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response and saw that Body io.ReadCloser i.e. Body is of type io.ReaderCloser. In order to know what is io.ReaderCloser, I clicked on the hyperlink and saw that http://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser is an interface that implements two methods Reader and Closer. Looking at this I thought I could do this

```
line, _ , err := response.Body.Reader.ReadLine()
```

Go compiler then gave me the error there is no method or type Reader in response.Body. I think conceptually I am having a problem of understanding why I could not do this. Maybe I am thinking too much in java terms. I would appreciate if somebody could point out my misunderstanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR**

Body *is* a `Reader`. It doesn't contain one. Just call `Reader` methods directly on `Body`.

**Gory Details**

10 second intro to Go interfaces: A set of methods that types must implement, if it has all the methods, it implements the interface, period.

Next is what just bit you, embedding. If we have an interface `Foo`

```
type Foo interface {
    FooIt() error
}
```

and we want another interface also with the method `FooIt` + some stuff, we can "embed" the interface like this.

```
type FooPlusPlus interface {
    Foo // This embeds Foo in FooPlusPlus, making all of Foo's methods
        // part of FooPlusPlus's method pool.
    FooItAll() (bool, error)
}
```

Embedding provides a nice way to compose related interfaces, like `Reader` and `Closer`. You can *kinda* think of it like inheriting in Java land. You don't explicitly ask for the embedded interface any more than you'd ask for a parent class in Java with a subclass.

Now to implement `FooPlusPlus`

```
 type Demo int
 func (_ *Demo) FooIt() error {return nil}
 func (_ *Demo) FooItAll() (bool, error) {return false, nil}
```

And viola, now Demo is a `FooPlusPlus`.

Comment: So `Body` *is* a `Reader`, and you can call `Reader` methods directly from `Body`, like `response.Body.Read()`

Comment: Hmm, ok I think it is make sense now since io.ReadCloser implements both Reader and Closer Interface, I can just do response.Body.ReadLine()

Comment: io.Reader only has one method: Read. I think you're looking at bufio.Reader which has a ReadLine method. You can get a bufio.Reader from any io.Reader with bufio.NewReader: http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewReader (I hope I didn't confuse myself and get any of that wrong :)